# How can I new a promise without channel in netty 4.1

Tags: java, promise, netty

I found two way to new a promise

1. http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOutboundInvoker.html#newPromise()

This way need an existed channel instance

2. http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise.html#DefaultPromise()

This method is protected

If i can new a generic promise without channel ?

Answer (score 1):

`EventExecutor.newPromise()`.

See also: 
http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutor.html#newPromise()